# Submitting Open Graph action: not authentic Open Graph story

Tags: ios, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to submit an Open Graph action ('share') with an Object ('post') and have been asked to supply screenshots of the published story on the test user's timeline.

When performing the action, this is posted to the timeline:
[image: timeline activity view]

and when clicking on the time ('2 minutes ago' etc) this view:

[image: activity view]

I have been told by the submissions team that this is not an authentic open graph story and they are unwilling to help beyond referring me here. So I have no idea what exactly they mean by 'not authentic' or what exactly is wrong.

Could anybody shed any light on this?

(tagged iOS as I'm performing the action from an iOS app - but the same thing happens via JS - but I need to use a non-fb tag)

Many thanks,

Jon

Comment: I am trying the same thing. And mine is posting in user's activity. But not in the user's timeline. Can you share your code here?.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue here is that the "Share" verb is already used by Facebook to mean a specific thing so it is disallowed as an Open Graph verb. Perhaps you could come up with a different verb? Are you sharing this to Facebook or only with in the scope of your app? If you are sharing to Facebook via the APIs or dialogs then Facebook will automatically create a share story.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case, I've tried with another verb but it results in the same screenshots.

I'm using the iOS SDK requestWithGraphPath:andParams:andHttpMethod:andDelegate: to post to me/[namespace]:action.

As I said, the action seems to be published successfully, just that the resulting published story is not an 'authentic open graph story'

Comment: What was the other verb you tried? Did the screen shots still have the word "shared" in them?

Comment: I used Post. I actually created a new action and object from scratch, so I didn't leave any old stuff in there.

Comment: I think "Posted" sounds like an already used term in Facebook lingo. try something different perhaps? For example "flung" or "selected" etc?